Embedding VTK/Vedo in QML (PyQT5)
I'm trying to create a qt vedo application, with QML for UI design. But when I run it, the button shows but not the vedo plotter. I've only found examples in C++ that use frame buffer objects, but nothing in python. I am completely new to this so would appreciate any help I can get. Currently using PyQT5.15.11 and VTK 9.3.1.
main.py
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtQml     import qmlRegisterType, QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

from vedo                                     import Mesh, Plotter
from vtk                                      import *
from vtkmodules.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor

import sys


class VedoWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        # Call super class constructor
        super().__init__(parent)

        
        # Set up layout
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Set up VTK widget
        self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.vtkWidget)

        # Initialize Vedo plotter
        self.plt = Plotter(qt_widget=self.vtkWidget, bg="white")

        # Load a sample mesh
        self.mesh = Mesh("assets/head.stl").c("lightgray")
        self.plt.add(self.mesh)

        # Show the VTK render window
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.plt.renderer)
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().Render()
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor().Start()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Create Qt application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Create QML engine
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    # Register custom QML types
    qmlRegisterType(VedoWidget, 'QtVTK', 1, 0, 'VedoWidget')

    # Load main QML file
    engine.load(QUrl('resources/main.qml'))

    # Validate QML file loaded successfully
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    # Exit program gracefully
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

main.qml
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtVTK 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600

    Rectangle {
        width: 800
        height: 600

        VedoWidget
        {
        }
    }

    Button {
        text: "Click Me"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}


